# Ethernet over Powerline 'above' the network

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

As of this week, our house is now connected to Australia's NBN. What this means is, we now have an 'NBN Modem' fixed to our wall, which was provided to us by the NBN Co. This is in a different location to the old phone line, so we are running Ethernet over Powerline adaptors from the modem to the location of our router (where the phone line previously was).

There are a total of 4 Ethernet over Powerline adapters around the house. One is connected to the NBN Modem, another is connected to the WAN port of the router. The other two are connected to two computers.

The first thing I find strange is that these two computers have internet access - despite there being no DHCP server to connect to. It seems they are getting IPv6 addresses, and the two machines can talk to each other in that respect, but when I try and ping their IPv4 address, it often gets lost.

The main problem though is that one of these computers is my home server, and contains my printer. My main machine is a laptop, so it's connected to the wireless. I need a solution where I can see my server on the network (preferably avoiding purchasing another Powerline adaptor.

Is it possible, that if I disable the DHCP server on the router (A Linksys E3000), that somehow the NBN Modem will provide each device on the network an IPv6 address to (a) give each machine network access and (b) to allow me to view the devices that are 'above' the wireless network.

If that won't work, is there another solution that I could try that doesn't involve moving the router (it's possible, but at the far end of the house) or purchasing any more equipment?

```
                  NBN Modem
                      |
                  PoE Device
                      |
         Server       |          Computer
           |----------*--------------|
       PoE Device     |         PoE Device
                      |
                  PoE Device
                      | (WAN Port)
                    Router
     -----------------|-----------------
    /       /         |         \       \
 Laptop   Phone    Computer   Phone   Laptop
```

Comment: I use PoEs at the LAN portion, so I don't have to connect each device directly to the router.  And i've never seen devices that i'd have thought are on your LAN, connected between the modem and router, which is the WAN portion!

Comment: what goes down the WAN cable and what goes down LAN cables, would I suppose be completely different and you've mixed them both.  How about a very long rugged ethernet/cat.. cable going all the way from modem to router. I suppose alternatively, you could give the server and computer in the middle WAN portion, static ipv4 addresses. would that work for you?

Comment: Your title mentions *"Ethernet over Powerline"* but your diagram uses the acronym *"PoE"*.  Those are not synonymous!  PoE is for delivering power over an Ethernet 10/100 cable.  Your setup (as described) has no need for PoE.  You should correct your diagram.

Comment: Your current configuration has your Server and one Computer exposed to the Internet and therefore vulnerable to attack. Try visiting the [Shields Up! site](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) from each of your PCs (especially your exposed server and PC) to evaluate the different vulnerabilities (especially file sharing and open ports). You want/need to have all of your PCs on the LAN (not the WAN) side of the router, not just for DHCP service, but also for NAT and firewall protection.